# Net not learning in MINST with peculiar cost function

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, loss-functions, kullback-leibler, uncertainty

I've been 12 hours non stop trying to solve this. Defeated, I came here to see if someone can help:

I'm training a LeNet architecture with MNIST in Pytorch, using the loss function from eq(5) this poster:

https://github.com/atilberk/evidential-deep-learning-to-quantify-classification-uncertainty/blob/master/poster.pdf

In that Github there is the code implemented in TensorFlow, and I am trying to apply it in Pytorch. The thing is: In TensorFlow it works perfectly, in Pytorch I can train the net with MNIST using Cross Entropy loss, but when I change to the new loss, it just doesn't learn (the value of the loss remains almost constant).

I've look everywhere in my code: The loss of eq(5) works the same for me in Pytorch as in TensorFlow, the outputs of each of the layers are smaller in Pytorch than in TensorFlow, but when I train in Pytorch with Cross Entropy they are still small but learning occurs.

I have certainly no idea what to look for, or where could it be my mistake.

This is the loss:

```
def loss_eq5(p, alpha, K, glob, ann):
S = torch.sum(alpha, 1, keepdims=True)
loglikelihood = torch.sum((p-(alpha/S))**2, 1, keepdims=True) + torch.sum(alpha*(S-alpha)/(S*S*(S+1)), 1, keepdims=True)
KL_reg = torch.min(torch.tensor(1), glob/ann) * KL((alpha - 1)*(1-p) + 1 , K)
return loglikelihood + KL_reg
```

And this is the training procedure:

```
def train(epoch):
global cur_batch_win
net.train()
loss_list, batch_list = [], []
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(data_train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    output = net(images)

    evidence = nn.ReLU()
    evidencia = evidence(output)
    alpha = evidencia + 1

    p = np.zeros([images.shape[0],K])
    p[np.arange(images.shape[0]), labels] = 1

    loss = torch.mean(loss_eq5(torch.tensor(p), alpha, K, torch.tensor(epoch), torch.tensor(550)))

    loss_list.append(loss.detach().cpu().item())
    batch_list.append(i+1)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('Train - Epoch %d, Batch: %d, Loss: %f' % (epoch, i, loss.detach().cpu().item()))


    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Thank you very much in advance!

FULL WORKING CODE:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from collections import OrderedDict
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import sampler
from torchvision.datasets.mnist import MNIST
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as T
import numpy as np


### LOSS:
def loss_eq5(p, alpha, K, glob, ann):
   S = torch.sum(alpha, 1, keepdims=True)
   loglikelihood = torch.sum((p-(alpha/S))**2, 1, keepdims=True) + torch.sum(alpha*(S-alpha)/(S*S*(S+1)), 1, keepdims=True)
   KL_reg = torch.min(torch.tensor(1), glob/ann) * KL((alpha - 1)*(1-p) + 1 , K)
   return loglikelihood + KL_reg

def KL(alpha, K):
   beta = torch.tensor(np.ones((1,K)))
   S_alpha = torch.sum(alpha,1, keepdims=True)

   KL = torch.sum((alpha - beta)*(torch.digamma(alpha)- 
   torch.digamma(S_alpha)),1,keepdims=True) + \
   torch.lgamma(S_alpha) - torch.sum(torch.lgamma(alpha),1,keepdims=True) + \
   torch.sum(torch.lgamma(beta),1,keepdims=True) - torch.lgamma(torch.sum(beta,1,keepdims=True))
return KL

### CONVNET:
class C1(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(C1, self).__init__()

    self.c1 = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('c1', nn.Conv2d(1, 20, kernel_size=(5, 5))),
        ('relu1', nn.ReLU()),
        ('s1', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2))
    ]))

def forward(self, img):
    output = self.c1(img)
    return output


class C2(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(C2, self).__init__()

    self.c2 = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('c2', nn.Conv2d(20, 50, kernel_size=(5, 5))),
        ('relu2', nn.ReLU()),
        ('s2', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2))
    ]))

def forward(self, img):
    output = self.c2(img)
    return output

class F4(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(F4, self).__init__()

    self.f4 = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('f4', nn.Linear(1250, 500)),
        ('relu4', nn.ReLU())
    ]))

def forward(self, img):
    output = self.f4(img)
    return output


class F5(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(F5, self).__init__()

    self.f5 = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('f5', nn.Linear(500, 10))
    ]))

def forward(self, img):
    output = self.f5(img)
    return output


class LeNet5(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super(LeNet5, self).__init__()

    self.c1 = C1()
    self.c2 = C2() 
    self.f4 = F4() 
    self.f5 = F5() 

def forward(self, img):
    out1 = self.c1(img)
    out2 = self.c2(out1)

    out22 = out2.view(out2.size(0), -1)

    out3 = self.f4(out22)
    output = self.f5(out3)
    return out1, out2, out3, output

###DATA LOADING:

!wget www.di.ens.fr/~lelarge/MNIST.tar.gz
!tar -zxvf MNIST.tar.gz

from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision import transforms

data_train = MNIST('./', download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([ 
transforms.Resize((32, 32)), transforms.ToTensor() ]), train=True)
data_test = MNIST('./' ,download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([ 
transforms.Resize((32, 32)), transforms.ToTensor() ]), train=False)

data_train_loader = DataLoader(data_train, batch_size=256, shuffle=True, 
num_workers=8)
data_test_loader = DataLoader(data_test, batch_size=1024, num_workers=8)

net = LeNet5()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=2e-3)
K=10
net = LeNet5()

cur_batch_win = None
cur_batch_win_opts = {
'title': 'Epoch Loss Trace',
'xlabel': 'Batch Number',
'ylabel': 'Loss',
'width': 1200,
'height': 600,
}

#### TRAINING
def train(epoch):
global cur_batch_win
net.train()
loss_list, batch_list = [], []
for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(data_train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    out1, out2, out3, output = net(images)

    evidence = nn.ReLU()
    evidencia = evidence(output)
    alpha = evidencia + 1

    p = np.zeros([images.shape[0],K])
    p[np.arange(images.shape[0]), labels] = 1

    loss = torch.mean(loss_eq5(torch.tensor(p), alpha, K, torch.tensor(epoch), torch.tensor(550)))

    loss_list.append(loss.detach().cpu().item())
    batch_list.append(i+1)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        print('Train - Epoch %d, Batch: %d, Loss: %f' % (epoch, i, loss.detach().cpu().item()))


    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

train(1)
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is make unit tests and verify that the two implementations are computing the same thing.

Comment: Hi! I think I have already done it. I checked the differences in each layer. There is one major diffrence between TF y Pytorch: In Pytorch the output is of the order $10^{-2}$ and in TF of order $10$.
BUT when I use in Pytorch cross entropy, the output is in the same order ($10^{-2}$) and it learns still. What else should I look for?

Comment: Because the test outlined in your comment is comparing the *layers* of the network, it's not a test of the loss function itself. Additionally, you've found some discrepancies, so there is something (perhaps random initialization, perhaps another difference) which is causing the two models to give different answers. By contrast, a unit test would test the loss function in isolation. If I code some function like $f(x)=x^2+\sin(x)$ in torch, its values should match the function $g(x) = x^2 + \sin(x)$ coded in TF, for all inputs $x$. If I discover that $f(x) \neq g(x)$, then I know there's a bug.

Comment: Oh, yes but I've done that too! I ran the loss function in Pytorch and TF with the same input tensor, and I got the same outputs. That made me think that the code of the loss was right.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a minimal, reproducible example of a pytorch network that doesn't learn? It doesn't need to be (and probably shouldn't be) an ornate, many-layered network. Just something that exhibits the behavior, compared to the equivalent TF network that doesn't learn (which should also be supplied).

Comment: Yes! I will do it inmediately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121199/discussion-between-cosapocha-and-sycorax).